# jQuery - How can I append an element from one div to another only if the div is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

```
<div id="apply"></div>
<div id="droppable_slots">
    <div class="slot 1">1</div>
    <div class="slot 2">2</div>
    <div class="slot 3">3</div>
</div>
```

How can I use jquery to loop through each of the slot div's and check them to see whether the div's only have the text (1,2,3) character within them, then append the apply div if it's true?

Comment: I don't understand, it's a question why am I getting - rep :S

Comment: Probably because "this question does not show any research effort"—in other words, we're not sure what you've tried. Can you post some code that you've worked on that doesn't work? The question itself is fine, though. Have you looked at the jQuery docs? You'll probably want to check the `each()` and `text()` methods.

Comment: I've tried the each() syntax but can't get it to work with the selector structure, which is why I asked for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var whitelist = ["1","2","3"];
$(".slot").each(function(){
    if(whitelist.indexOf($(this).text()) !== -1) {
        $(this).append($("#apply").clone());
    }
});
```